# M2 Catalog Search: Getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when trying to access a 'search term' assigned to an URL

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I am trying to fine tune my catalog search. From the backend I've assigned, for example, to the following search term 'iphone camera' the following URL: https://example.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?brand=48&mobile_camera_type=260%2C261&q=iphone+camera

Now when I am entering the search term in the frontend, I am unable to access the aforementioned assigned page, and instead have been getting 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the search controller without a query parameter Magento will redirect to the referrer URL (or homepage if no referrer is found). With your search term based redirect you produce an infinite loop:

1. URL call:
   `/catalogsearch/result/index/?brand=48&mobile_camera_type=260%2C261&q=iphone+camera`
2. match redirect for search term `iphone camera` and call redirect:
   `/catalogsearch/result/index/?brand=48&mobile_camera_type=260%2C261`
3. search result controller makes redirect to referrer, because there is no query parameter and calls:
   `/catalogsearch/result/index/?brand=48&mobile_camera_type=260%2C261&q=iphone+camera`

You shouldn't use URLs with search result controller whithout query parameter if you want to avoid such redirect situations.